# Need help with SharePoint

Tags: 2013

Two times a day, a SharePoint snapshot starts up. - In the SQL Server Log this message appears;

> 12/31/2015 9:11:45AM Starting up database
>   'WSS_INTRANET_AZDOA_GOV_20151231_161138_1989585'. When staff comes
>   into work to use SharePoint, the transactions get blocked by this
>   query;
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO [WSS_INTRANET_AZDOA_GOV].[dbo].[DocStreams] 
>     (DocId,SiteId,Partition,BSN,Size,Content,RbsId,Type,ExpirationUTC) 
> SELECT 
>     DocId,N'de89fa2b-bdb9-4586-8316-4f4a3e0230a1',Partition,BSN,Size,Content,NULL,Type,ExpirationUTC 
> FROM 
>     [WSS_INTRANET_AZDOA_GOV_20151231_161138_1989585].[dbo].[DocStreams] 
> WHERE 
>     SiteId=@PARTITION_KEY_0
> ```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?  And how I can stop it from happening?

Comment: can you tell us what is the SQL configuration including server architecture/topology

Comment: SQL Server 2012 on an EC2 instance in the AWS Cloud

Comment: This query is inserting document content (Word, Excel, etc.) into DocStreams. What do you mean by "SharePoint snapshot"?

Comment: When this database starts up twice a day, I could not do anything with it because SQL Server recognizes it as a snapshot - I tried to put it into Single user mode. So getting back to my original question Why is data from the snapshot being inserted into the main SharePoint database, WSS_INTRANET_AZDOA_GOV?